# how to add filter for json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am having many such entries in my json data. The "type"  consists of tw attributes i.e. income and expense. How to print the "label" which have type="expense" in using JavaScript. 
This json data below is just an example.
[Check the image to get a better idea of json data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EldyO.png)

```
  "expenses_veterinary":{
      label:"Veterinary, breeding, and medicine"
      name:"expenses_veterinary"
      total:0
      type:"expense"
  }
console.log($ctrl.gold_standard_categories); prints all the json data.
```

I tried the code written below but its not working.

```
  if($ctrl.gold_standard_categories.name.type=expense){
       console.log($ctrl.gold_standard_categories.label);
  }
```

Comment: JSON.parse($ctrl.gold_standard_categories)[0].label ?

Answer (score 0):

It prints all the data because of the single equals sign in your `if` statement.

It means you are always trying to assign the value *"expense"* to your `type` property and so the `if` statement will always evaluate to true.

What you are intending to do is [compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control) the values, not assign a value.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/yxL4rpj2/

assume that in `var` `money` you store the json response

```
var grouppedMoney = {
    expenses: [],
    incomes: []
 };

for(var i = 0; i <= money.length - 1; i++){

    for(moneyType in money[i]){
    var _typeString = money[i][moneyType].type == 'expense' ? 'expenses' : 'incomes';

    grouppedMoney[_typeString].push(money[i][moneyType]);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic example.Iterate over your object and see `type` value is equal to `expense` then print the `label` value.

```js
var data = {
"expenses_veterinary":{
      "label":"Veterinary, breeding, and medicine",
      "name":"expenses_veterinary",
      "total":0,
      "type":"income"
  },
  
  "expenses_car":{
      "label":"bus and truck",
      "name":"expenses_car",
      "total":0,
      "type":"expense"
  }
};
 
for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
 if(data[property]['type']=='expense'){
     console.log(data[property]['label']);
 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using AngularJS (`$ctrl`) so you may consider using either native angular filters or custom filter to do this.

BTW, using vanilla JS, this simple loop will work :

```
for(var key in jsonData) {
  if("expense" === jsonData[key]["type"]) {
    console.log(jsonData[key]["label"]);
  }
}
```

**Sample snippet**

```js
var jsonData = {
  "expensesigoods": {
    "name": "expenses_goods",
    "label": "Cost of goods sold",
    "type": "expense",
    "total": 0
  },
  "expensesicar": {
    "name": "expenses_car",
    "label": "Car and truck expenses",
    "type": "expense",
    "total": 0
  },
  "expensesichemicals": {
    "name": "expenses_chemicals",
    "label": "Chemicals",
    "type": "expense",
    "total": 0
  },
  "expensesiconservation": {
    "name": "expenses_conservation",
    "label": "Conservation expenses",
    "type": "other",
    "total": 0
  }
}

for(var key in jsonData) {
  if("expense" === jsonData[key]["type"]) {
    console.log(jsonData[key]["label"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you used `Vanilla js`?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Vanilla JS is pure JS ^^

Comment: The original OP didn't tag `vanilla.js` or `angular.js`.

Comment: The original OP tag `javascript` which IS vanilla JS. And its sample use `$ctrl` which most of the time is angular. But it's just an assumption, that's why I didn't provide an additional angularjs snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Array.filter()` method to filter the data based on `type="expense"`.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fozhxye5/)

```js
var obj = {
  "expenses_goods":{
      "label":"expenses_goods",
      "name":"expenses goods",
      "total":0,
      "type":"income"
  },
  "expenses_cars":{
      "label":"expenses_cars",
      "name":"expenses cars",
      "total":0,
      "type":"expense"
  },
  "expenses_veterinary":{
      "label":"expenses_veterinary",
      "name":"expenses veterinary",
      "total":0,
      "type":"income"
  }
};

var res = Object.keys(obj).filter(item => { return obj[item].type == 'expense' });

for (var i in res) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = obj[res[i]].label;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```